# MP4 video in Flash player has no audio, has audio in MPC

Tags: flash, mp4

This page has some sample videos: [MP4 Videos in Flash Player](http://www.unctv.org/50years/test_converted_files_code.html)
The videos have audio when played in Media Player Classic; but when played in the Flash Player, generated using swfobject.js, it has no audio.

What's causing this?

Comment: There are a number of "undefined" traces in my debug log.  Like this: `view: volume: 100,undefined`.  Perhaps it has something to do with that...

Comment: QuickTime Player on my Mac also plays the video without audio, and reports that "An invalid sample description was found in the movie". I tested with the 50_yrs_blions_2.mp4 file.

Comment: Thanks, weltraumpirat and Lars. Now I'm trying to figure out how to fix this -- there are over 5600 of these files. Re-encoding will be painful. Any automated tools to take care of this?

Comment: Oh, 5600 files, that will be a lot of work, even with tools that can encode files from a list in a batch. Maybe you should not just take my word for it then, and investigate further if they really have to be re-encoded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be because of the audio codec used in the videos, I believe your videos has mpga encoded audio and Flash Player needs AAC encoded audio for H.264 video.

Comment: Thanks, Lars. Do the files need to be re-encoded again or is there any other solution?

Comment: Yes, I believe they have to be re-encoded, with attention to the audio codec used.